# Move up in DOM hierarchy using selenium

Tags: dom, selenium, webdriver

I want to access a DOM Element which is above in hierarchy to an element i have access of.

In the Attached ScreenShot I want to access the #pRow_22 which a Grand Grand Grand Parent of #ntsDiv_1. But I have the access to #ntsDiv_1 only. Please suggest me what to do in such a scenario

[image]

html code is like this:-

```
<tr id="pRow_22" style="border-bottom: 0;">
<td class="nameCell" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;">
    <div id="seller_22" class="product-sellercell">
        <a id="pLogoLink_22" target="_blank" href="/norob/ClickTracker.somethins..." onclick="setMerchLb('eComElectronics.com')" rel="nofollow">
        <div>
            <a id="ntsLink_1" rel="nofollow" onclick="return false;" href="#">
        </div>
        <div id="ntsDiv_1" class="mlt-pop-container" style="width: 250px; text-align: left; white-space: normal; top: 2340px; left: 131px; visibility: hidden;">
            <div class="mlt-pop-bg">
        </div>
        .
        .   
        </div>
</td>
```

Comment: yes query parent until the parent TR is obtained.

Comment: i have to do that using selenium API, how to do that

Comment: Oops, didn't notice that. I don't know anything about selenium, so sorry. I'll delete my comments above to leave room for more useful comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using xpath

```
.//a[contains(@id,'ntsLink_1')]/ancestor::tr
```

Comment: can you specify the exact path using abobe html snippet. i am not so comfotable with xpath

Comment: sorry i didnt understand your Adobe html snippet, but if u want use webdriver/selenium to access the TR element based on <a> tag the sample is driver.findElements(By.XPATH(".//a[contains(@id,'ntsLink_1')]/ancestor::tr")).click (or something like)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp you can get more info about xpath axes

Comment: ancestor::tr and the role of :: in it

Comment: ancestor- Selects all ancestors (parent, grandparent, etc.) of the current node, for usage of :: in simple words when you specify ::tr it selects only TR elements

Comment: is it possible to do this without this xpath? By Using css or DOM?

Answer (score 1):

**Try This** :

## ***By.cssSelector("a[id='ntsdiv_1']")***

suppose here is the hierarchy:

```
<div class="1">............  (suppose it's div 1 open)
  <div class="2">........    (div 2 open)
     <div class="3">.......  (div 3 open)
     </div>.....             (div 3 closed)  
     <div class="4">......   (div 4 open)  
     </div>.....             (div 4 closed)
   </div>.........           (div 2 closed)
</div>.........              (div 1 closed)
```

now, we want to access div 4

**Note**: div 3 and div 4 are of same level, these two are child of div 2 whose parent is div 1

We want to access class 4

we ac do it using xpath but the class of div 4 is not unique and the class 1 is, so you can traverse it as such:

By.xpath(".//div[@class='1']/div/div[2]")

*Explanation*: div[2] means it is going to access the class 1 which has div of class 3 and whose child has two div of classes class 3 and class 4 but i want to access the second div which has class 4 so, div[2].

***cssSelector***

sometimes we cannot access the path so, we can access it by using css selector, suppose we have a scenario as such

```
<div class="1">
    <rect class="2">
         <text class="3">
         </text>
    </rect>
</div>
```

to access the class of text

we use By.cssSelector as:

By.cssSelector("text[class='3']");